# nginx tcp balancer + exchange

Tags: nginx, load-balancing

My Nginx works like tcp balancer between users and Exchange cluster. Every thing works fine, but I'd like to add active checks.

For example IMAP service, after TCP session initiation service return banner: 
"IMAP4 service is ready"

I'd like to monitor this banner, if it fail, than host will remove from upstream.

How can I solve it? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Load imap module and you can do check as below:

```
check interval=5000 rise=2 fall=5 timeout=2000 type=imap;
```

nginx connects to the imap server, receives the greeting response to diagnose if the upstream server is alive.

Comment: thank you for your answer, but how can I monitor other multiple services?

Comment: I solved it with Consul+Consul template. This issue is closed. Thank you.